# def function to save variable data to a txt file writes it 3 times

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Learning python and messing with a simple GUI data entry/save to text file.
The problem I'm having is this following code works but writes it three times in the text file. Like it loops it 3 times.  Updated with full code, used PyQt Designer to make the Ui file.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class RefTracker(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
       super(RefTracker,self).__init__()
       loadUi('reftrack.ui',self)
       self.setWindowTitle('r134a Tracker')
       self.label7.setText(time.ctime())
      # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
      # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton2_clicked)
      # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton3_clicked)
       self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):

        cust = self.lineEdit.text()
        plate = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.label_13.setText(cust)
        self.label_14.setText(plate)
        f= open('data.txt','a')
        f.write('Customer Name: '+cust+'\n')
        f.write('Plate Number: '+plate+'\n')
        f.close()

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=RefTracker()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you certain you just didn't invoke the function multiple times?  It is being opened for "append" (`a+`) afterall.

Comment: the code looks good, it seems to me that the error is in another part of your code that does not show, provides a [mcve]

Comment: There's no way we could reproduce the issue with the code shown here

Comment: On top of the problems mentioned above, you never `close` the file. This is a bad idea, especially with writable files. It's _probably_ not your problem, but it never hurts to do it right instead of doing it wrong. The simplest way is to use `with open('data.txt', 'a+') as f:`, so it's guaranteed to close, even if you have an unexpected exception.

Comment: Added the closed file line.  No change.  Updated with full code, should I include the Ui file?

Comment: updated the code, now it only saves doubles.  Guess I have to move something to __init__ from what I've been finding.

Comment: @JeremyDennis 
check my answer and understand why we ask for a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc trying to figure a example that meets those requirements, that will run.  A non GUI example seems to run fine. I can say that if I put a exit() line at the end of the def on_pushButton_clicked function it writes to the data.txt file once and exits the program.  Something is looping with the button click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the .ui file, the method is called [`connectSlotsByName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName)

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
```

And according to the [`docs`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName):

> **void QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QObject *object)**
>
> Searches recursively for all child objects of the given object, and
>   connects matching signals from them to slots of object that follow the
>   following form:
>
> void `on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>)`; Let's assume
>   our object has a child object of type QPushButton with the object name
>   button1. The slot to catch the button's `clicked()` signal would be:
>
> ```
> void on_button1_clicked();
> ```
>
> If object itself has a properly set object name, its own signals are
>   also connected to its respective slots.

and in its case the slot matches that structure, so without using `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)` an implicit connection already exists.

And when you create the new connection, you will call the `on_pushButton_clicked` method twice.

For the above you have 2 alternatives:

1. Delete your connection:

---

```
class RefTracker(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
       super(RefTracker,self).__init__()
       loadUi('reftrack.ui',self)
       self.setWindowTitle('r134a Tracker')
       self.label7.setText(time.ctime())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):

        cust = self.lineEdit.text()
        plate = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.label_13.setText(cust)
        self.label_14.setText(plate)
        with open('data.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write('Customer Name: '+cust+'\n')
            f.write('Plate Number: '+plate+'\n')
```

2. Change the name to the slot:

---

```
class RefTracker(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
       super(RefTracker,self).__init__()
       loadUi('reftrack.ui',self)
       self.setWindowTitle('r134a Tracker')
       self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_slot)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_slot(self):

        cust = self.lineEdit.text()
        plate = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.label_13.setText(cust)
        self.label_14.setText(plate)
        with open('data.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write('Customer Name: '+cust+'\n')
            f.write('Plate Number: '+plate+'\n')
```